# Obtener número de registros en diferentes rangos

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

estoy intentando realizar una consulta SQL en la que tengo dos tablas, una tiene un campo de tiempo (horas, minutos y segundos) y la otra tiene un registro cada 5 minutos. Pongo un ejemplo de las tablas.

Tabla A

```
+----------------------------------+---------------+
| fecha                            | hora_y_minuto |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:10:42       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:13:22       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:16:42       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:26:15       |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
```

Tabla B

```
+----------------------------------+---------------+
| fecha_estadistica                | hora_y_minuto |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:00:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:05:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:10:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:15:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:20:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:25:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:30:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:35:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:40:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:45:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:50:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:55:00       |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |01:00:00       |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
```

Y lo que quiero obtener es una tabla final en la que se muestre la fecha de A, el campo **hora_y_minuto**
(llamado **inicio_intervalo**) de A, una columna adicional que sea una copia de la columna **hora_y_minuto** (llamado **fin_intervalo**) de A, pero con media hora de adelanto y una columna que sea el número de registros de la tabla B que, para cada **hora_y_minuto** de la tabla A me saque el total de registros que abarca en la tabla B entre **inicio_intervalo** y **fin_intervalo**.

El resultado que espero conseguir sería el siguiente:

```
+----------------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| fecha                            | inicio_intervalo | fin_intervalo    | count            |
+----------------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:10:42          |00:40:42          |7                 |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:13:22          |00:43:22          |6                 |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:16:42          |00:46:42          |6                 |
|          2020-01-07 00:00:00 UTC |00:26:15          |00:56:15          |6                 |
+----------------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Soy consciente de que habrá registros que se cuenten varias veces si pertenecen a varios intervalos, pero eso es el comportamiento deseado.

He probado con consultas como

```
select fecha_estadistica, cast(hora_y_minuto as TIME)) as hora_y_minuto, count (*) as total
from A
where cast(hora_y_minuto as TIME))>=
  (SELECT distinct cast(hora_y_minuto as TIME)) as fecha
  FROM B a1 join
  B a2 on a1.fecha_estadistica=a2.fecha_estadistica and 
  cast(a1.hora_y_minuto as TIME))=cast(a2.hora_y_minuto as TIME))
  where cast(a2.hora_y_minuto as TIME))>=cast(a1.hora_y_minuto as TIME))
  and cast(a2.hora_y_minuto as TIME))<=TIME_ADD(cast(REPLACE (a1.hora_y_minuto, ".", ":") as time), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
  order by fecha)
and
  (SELECT distinct TIME_ADD(cast(REPLACE (a2.hora_y_minuto, ".", ":") as time), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) as fecha2
  FROM B a1 join
  B a2 on a1.fecha_estadistica=a2.fecha_estadistica and 
  cast(a1.hora_y_minuto as TIME))=cast(a2.hora_y_minuto as TIME))
  where cast(a2.hora_y_minuto as TIME))>=cast(a1.hora_y_minuto as TIME))
  and cast(a2.hora_y_minuto as TIME))<=TIME_ADD(cast(REPLACE (a1.hora_y_minuto, ".", ":") as time), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
  order by fecha2)
```

Pero no consigo que me funcione. No soy una persona muy experimentada en bases de datos así que pido disculpas si se ven errores grandes.

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo que buscas con una simple consulta a la tabla de A y añadiendo un `SELECT COUNT(*)` a la tabla B para obtener el total de datos que hay en esa tabla en el intervalo de tiempo del valor de A + 30 minutos, de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT a.fecha, a.hora_y_minuto as inicio_intervalo, 
ADDTIME(A.HORA_Y_MINUTO, '00:30:00') as fin_intervalo, 
(select count(*) from B where ADDTIME(b.fecha_estadistica,b.hora_y_minuto) 
between ADDTIME(A.FECHA,A.HORA_Y_MINUTO) AND ADDTIME(ADDTIME(A.FECHA,A.HORA_Y_MINUTO), '00:30:00')) as total
FROM A;
```

Puedes ver las pruebas que he hecho en [este enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8582f/14).

Comment: Buenas, he probado el trozo de código que me has indicado y me sale el siguiente error

LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

Aclaración: estoy usando Bigquery.

Comment: Esta es la consulta que he probado

select A.fecha, cast(A.hora_real as time) as inicio_intervalo, TIME_ADD(cast(A.hora_real as time), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) as fin_intervalo,
(
  select count(*) from  B
  where DATETIME(B.fecha_estadistica, B.hora_y_minuto) 
    between DATETIME(cast(A.fecha as date),cast(A.hora_real as time)) AND DATETIME(cast(A.fecha as date),TIME_ADD(cast(A.hora_real as time), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))
) as total

from A

Comment: Que sql estas usando MS SQL o MySQL?

Comment: Estoy utilizando Google Bigquery, y según su documentación, utiliza ANSI SQL.